# Question while studying Lagrange Interpolation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

While studying Linear Algebra From Text book Hoffman Kunze I have following 2 questions in section Lagrange Interpolation.

[image]

Question 1 Just before equation 4-14 authors wrote that independent set{ $ P_{0} $, ..., $P_{n} $ } are basis of V. How do I prove that the set { $P_{0}$ , ...,$ P_{n} $ } span V?

Question 2 How using Theorem 7 of Chapter 2 , I can prove that Vandermonde Matrix is invertible?

Theorem 7 , chapter 2 is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{P_0,...,P_n\}$ span $V=\mathcal{P}_n$ the space of polynomials of order n then for arbitrary $p\in \mathcal{P}_n$ we must have that $p=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\alpha_iP_i(x)$ can be expressed in this basis for some $\alpha_i\in \mathbb{R}$.

Take $\alpha_i=p(x_i)$ for knots $x_i \neq x_j$ if $i\neq j$ and note by the definition of $P_i$ we have $P_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$ the kornecker delta.

Then for the Lagrange interpolation of $p$ follows $\widetilde{p}(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}p(x_i)P_i(x)$ where $\widetilde{p}(x_j)=p(x_j)$ and we note $\widetilde{p}\in \mathcal{P}_n$ since $P_i\in \mathcal{P}_n$.

Now lets define $g:=\widetilde{p} - p$. Note that $g\in \mathcal{P}_n$ since $\widetilde{p}, p\in \mathcal{P}_n$ and note also $g$ has $n+1$ zeros at the knots $x_j$. Therefore, $g$ musst be the zero polynomial $g=\widetilde{p} - p=0$ and it follows $\widetilde{p} = p$.

Answer (score 1):

Let a Vandermonde matrix be defined as a matrix $\mathbf{V}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $\mathbf{V}_{i,j}={x_i}^{j-1}$ for some $\underline{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$. I claim that
$$\det(\mathbf{V})=\prod_{1\leq i\leq j \leq n}(x_j-x_i)$$
As long as all of the $x_i$ and $x_j$ are distinct, each term of the product will be nonzero, thus the determinant will be nonzero thus $\mathbf{V}$ will be invertible. Linked below is a proof of the above.

[Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Proofs)